# Mysql tinyint to datestamp

Tags: mysql

I would like to convert a mysql column from tinyint(1) which I am using just as a Boolean to a timestamp however I would like to preserve the existing data by inserting a date into the row when true.

So can I alter table columns while taking into consideration existing data?

I can do this with by adding another column and moving the data over, however can I do this in an alter query?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correct, something like that should work

```
ALTER TABLE "<table>" ADD COLUMN "<timestampcolumn>" datetime;
UPDATE "<table>" SET "<timestampcolumn>" = now() WHERE "<tinyintcolumn>" = 1;
ALTER TABLE "<table>" DROP COLUMN "<tinyintcolumn>"
```

It's important that you cannot save a timestamp into a tinyint, so you have to add a new column for your timestamp.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I am trying to alter the column data type from tinyint to timestamp.

Comment: this is not possible. You have to add a new column, fill it and then maybe remove the old one.

Comment: Yeah I already said that in my question, I was wondering if mysql had the ability to convert a column data type and  take into consideration the existing data.